# How do I check my DVD drive's region settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, regional-settings

I have installed Windows 7 on my laptop. When I put a movie in the DVD drive, the video player starts up and tells me 'THIS DISC IS NOT FORMATTED TO PLAY IN THIS REGION'. I have changed the DVD region a few times in the past but while I was in Windows XP I changed the region to Region 1.

I cannot find how to check the DVD region setting in Windows 7 (it's not located on the properties page of the DVD anymore. Does anybody know how to check the DVD region in Windows 7?

[image]

Update: If I connect an external USB DVD drive I can see the DVD region tab on the hardware properties dialog. I guess there is some compatibility problem with my internal DVD drive and Windows 7 (as I said I was able to inspect/change the DVD region in Windows XP).

Solution: I think I had used LtnRPC in the past to remove the region from my DVD drive. It looks like Windows 7 does not like region free DVD drives (at least mine anyway). I was able to use LtnRPC to reset the region back to 1. I can now see the region tab on the DVD drive's hardware properties.

Comment: I have uploaded a screen snapshot showing the lack of region settings for my DVD drive http://screencast.com/t/YjhlYzJmYm

Comment: in case you wonder about the 2 Base System Devices in the device manager, that'd be the SD card reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to see whether or not the DVD drive is locked by a region code.

**[Drive Region Info](http://download.chip.eu/en/Drive-Region-Info-2.2_56031.html)** is a simple freeware and portable tool that lets you know if your DVD drive is locked to any particular 'region'.

[image]

If your drive is locked after five changes you can use **[LtnRPC](http://dhc014.rpc1.org/LtnRPC/)**, a Region Free Utility for Lite-ON manufactured drives (your Sony DW-Q58A drive was manufactured by LiteOn) to reset the count or make the drive 'region free' altogether.

Comment: I will check it out once I have my AV software installed.

Comment: Funnily enough, I think I had used LtnRPC before because when I checked the region setting in XP the drive said 'no region'. Despite this Windows 7 would not play my region 1 'Office Space' DVD.

Comment: Here is my region info http://screencast.com/t/MmE2OTRhO. Maybe Windows 7 is not happy with region free DVD players.

Comment: With LtnRPC I was able to fix the problem. It looks like Windows 7 is not happy with region free DVD drives. I ran LtnRPC and was able to set the region back to 1. From then on Windows 7 allowed me to play my DVDs.

Comment: Cannot recommend downloading Drive Region Info. My Chrome warned after downloading that a virus has been detected in the file. Save yourself possible problems and use John T's answer which requires no additional software.

Answer (score 5):

- Right-click the DVD drive and select **properties**
- Under the **Hardware** tab, click **properties**
- Highlight the DVD drive and click on it
- Navigate to the **DVD Region** tab and modify it accordingly

Comment: I have no DVD Region tab http://screencast.com/t/MDg5MmU2Z

Comment: it is locked from too many changes you can use the tool in molly answer to see

Comment: yep, 5 changes, that's it.

Comment: The strange thing is that because I could not see the region tab in Windows 7, I booted into Windows XP and it let me change the region to region 1 but when I booted back into Windows 7 I still get the region error when I try to play the region 1 DVD.

Answer (score 1):

> it's not located on the hard properties page of the DVD anymore

I opened up Device Manager, went to Properties for my DVD drive and there was a change DVD region option, same as there's always been?

Comment: Perhaps it shows up for you, but it sounds like it didn't for the OP.