# Are PC DVD devices affected by DVD region?

Tags: windows, dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check my DVD drive's region settings in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/102786/how-do-i-check-my-dvd-drives-region-settings-in-windows-7)

Is there a restriction on what DVD region I can play? How is it implemented Is it restricted on software (applications such as Windows Media Player/VLC), OS, driver or hardware?

Answer (score 1):

DVD region settings are applicable for most PC-DVD drives and are set at DVD drive firmware level

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Playback_Control) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code#Computer_DVD_drives) also depending on the drive there may ber RPC-1 firmware available from [here](http://forum.rpc1.org/portal.php)

Answer (score 1):

See this other answer: [Is the Region Code setting a property of the external DVD drive or the OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/366533/is-the-region-code-setting-a-property-of-the-external-dvd-drive-or-the-os) - some software can bypass the region coding by doing the decryption in software rather than hardware. VLC is quite often successful at this.